# Will I be forced to update my iOS app in HTTPS in 2017?

Tags: ios, http, https, app-transport-security, wwdc

I actually have published an application in AppStore that works over HTTP. Will I be forced to update my app to work on HTTPS before 2017 or it will still be working as it is? What happens if I don't update my app before 2017? Please, give me a feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app will continue to work after Apple starts requiring justification for using App Transport Secutiry exceptions.  Apple's increased restrictions (starting 1/1/2017) are part of the submit process.  If you want to submit a binary (either for a new app, or an update to your existing app), if you have and have ATS exceptions in your Info.plist, it is likely that Apple will require a written justification for the exceptions and it will be up to Apple if your justifications are acceptable.  Note that there are some exceptions (like forward secrecy) that Apple is allowing without the need for justification.

It sounds like you either submitted your app to the store before ATS was being enforced, or you simply put in the blanket `NSAllowArbitraryLoads` exception that is a popular (if flawed) answer here on Stack Overflow.

Just note that if you don't fix the problem (by upgrading the server to support https) you may be able to submit updates to your app if Apple doesn't feel your justification is enough.  However, your existing app in the store will continue to function as it does today.